# Will The execution of vm-exit cause process switch?

Tags: kernel, virtualization, hypervisor

Assuming that a process in guest cause VM-EXIT, and then it trapped into host mode. If I execute PsGetCurrentProcess in hypervisor, could I get the process caused VM-exit. I know the VM-exit must cause the CPU context switch, and it include the CR3 regiter and so on. So will The execution of vm-exit  cause process switch?

Comment: I'm not sure what PsGetCurrentProcess is, but it may not even exist in both the guest and the host (or VMM). If it does exist in both places, then when you're in the host, it would return information about the host process, not the guest process.

Comment: Your question doesn't have an answer, because the process running in the VMM (if any) has no relation to the process running in the guest. But I wouldn't call that a process switch. The host or VMM doesn't know anything about processes running in the guest. The guest OS may not even have a process structure that makes any sense to the host. For example, suppose the guest is running DOS.

Comment: @prl I agree with you. It's my problem, it shouldn't be called process switch. But I read the code of one hypervisor which use PsGetCurrentProcess to capture the process caused vm-exit in guest. Do you think it is feasible?

Comment: In some VMMs, each VM is represented by a process in the host OS, and each virtual CPU in the VM is represented by a host thread. Perhaps that is what it is looking up?